# IBM worklight How to display a dynamic list using javascript + framework 7

Tags: javascript, html, ibm-mobilefirst, entity-framework-core

i need to create a dynamic list of some data that is in json

my js.

```
function displayFeeds(items){
        var ul = $('#Mylist');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
             var li = $('<li/>').html(items[i].ID);
             li.append($('<li/>').html(items[i].ADDRESS));
             li.append($('<hr>'));
             ul.append(li);
       }
    }
```

my html

```
<div  class="list-block">
            <ul id="Mylist">
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="item-title">Item</div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: Do you have an error, you haven't told us what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like this is related to Framework7 IMO. IMO the real question here is how to take the response ("items") and display it.
I am also missing any errors you might see in Chrome's DevTools console (I assume you previewed it first...).

Try changing your JavaScript to the following, just as a test.
Afterwards you can change the 'layout' accordingly.

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.invocationResult.resultSet.length; i++) {
       $("#Mylist").append("<li><item[i].ID</li>"); 
};
```

Related questions:

- [How to retrieve images from existing database using sql/http adapter from worklight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708346/how-to-retrieve-images-from-existing-database-using-sql-http-adapter-from-workli/)
- [Worklight and jquery: I want fetch links present in the xml and want tag them with the row dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303422/worklight-and-jquery-i-want-fetch-links-present-in-the-xml-and-want-tag-them-wi)